# On what grounds do we reject showing one and only one item in a grid?

Tags: grid

A colleague of mine recently showed a single entity, in a grid. In this form, we have three sections:

1. A section which shows the main entity (say a school)
2. A section which shows a vote form (each student can vote for a school)
3. A section which shows the votes of other people for that single entity (for that single school)

Now, my colleague shows that single entity (school in this example) in a grid. I rejected this design, as I think grid semantically means a mesh, a tabular representation of data. But I have no solid reasoning to support that "showing one item in a grid is bad design and results in bad user experience".

What reasons can we bring forward?

Comment: Are there times where there can be more than 1 item in that same grid? If so, I'd lean towards leaving the grid component to promote consistency, i.e. sometimes you would visit the page and it would have a grid, sometimes it would have a completely different layout

Comment: @ChrisMontgomery, it only contains one, and only one item. Not zero items, neither more than one items. The cardinality/quantifier is {1}.

Comment: Does the grid have a vertical scroll bar, and/or space for multiple lines? If not, how does it look different from a bunch of labelled fields? Are these values read-only?

Answer (score 2):

Explain to your colleague that every data representation has its own purpose.

1. **A grid** is supposed to be used for displaying a collection of multi-dimensional elements. For example, [a Market Watchlist](http://www.appsfinder.fr/images/android/screenshots/SS_10463_0.png).
2. **A List** is supposed to be used for displaying a collection of single-dimensional elements or multi-dimensional data represented into a single cell to create a grid-like structure with a single column. For example, [any top-list](http://cdn.toucharcade.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/watchlist.png) like: list of online users, search suggestions, etc.
3. **A Badge** is what you usually use to display information about a *single* object with multiple properties. For example, [a stock information tile](http://www.downloadcheapapp.com/iappimg/980/itrade-stock-market-simulator-screenshot-2.jpg).

Also, if you decide to show a table that contains a single entry at all times, then it just makes the representation too linear to engage the user.

Hope this helps!